# Variable doesn't work as it should

Tags: javascript, html

At first, my variable is set to zero. Then, after some questions answered correctly, the variable increases its value and it also shows me when I try it by `alert('')`. But when I try to write the variable as a text inside the HTML, it DOES show me, but I can't see increased number. I just see zero. It didn't even count to my variable. Can anyone explain me why? I'm posting a code here.

html:

```
<div class="textpadding">
  <h1>
    <center>
      <font face ="Kozuka"><b><p id="hihi"></p></div></b></font>
    </center>
  </h1>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var points = 0;
```

and down a bit, there's this command

```
document.getElementById("hihi").innerHTML = "Correct answers: " + points;
```

All these JavaScript things are inside the file.js. I don't know what's wrong with that.

javascript:

```
points = 0
var questions = 50;
function outoftime()
{

}

function opentest()
{
    window.open("questions.html");
}

function checkanswers()
{
   if(document.getElementById('3').checked) 
   {
      points++;
   }

   if(document.getElementById('5').checked) 
   {
      points++;
   }

   if(document.getElementById('10').checked) 
   {
      points++;
   }
  window.open('resulteng.html'); 
}
document.getElementById("hihi").innerHTML = "Correct answers: " + points;
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: Eh, I'm sorry, then.

Comment: You have an `</div>` too many.

Comment: Is that the reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: Unable to reproduce: See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLmqam00/)

Comment: You need to move the last line inside the `checkanswers()` function. It doesn't update automatically, you have to set the innerHTML again every time the points change.

Comment: I did so, but it it disappeared. And how am I supposed to do that? If you'd be so kind...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 'var' in  `var points = 0` -> Should be just `points = 0`. That makes it a Global variable instead of a local one. I believe that that will do the trick.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan and it was actually what I meant! Sorry for the typo, already edited it.

Comment: even if I deleted 'var' from there, it still doesn't work.. I'm trying to count something to the variable inside the function.

Comment: Then I suggest as @JJJ said, post more information or a complete example, so we can have a more complete picture.

Comment: You've got it there, bro.

Answer (score -1):

if i were you,I'll create new class(completely optional),where the increment takes place each of the iteration .
inside you put post-increment factors:

```
(x=0;x<10;x++)
{
var = var+1 ;
}
```

just my two cents,others might have different thoughts.All the best mate .

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to answer the question asked by the OP.